# How do I add an image to the header? is there a code?

Tags: html

[image]
şimdiden teşekür ederim.
how do i add a picture here?
How can I install a thumbnail there?
is there a shortcode.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a **favicon**.

You need to generate a .ico-File and put them into your project directory. Here is a simple generator: https://www.icoconverter.com

Then you can add the following code into your `<head>` element, next to your `<title>`

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Make sure you name the generated file `favicon.ico`.

This way most browsers will support it!